# Can not replace "?" by "$'", it so weird

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the statement below:

```
"(?)".replace("?", "$'")
```

My expectation is:

```
($')
```

But the result actually is:

```
())
```

How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `$$'` if you want replace to `$'` because `$'` is a special replacement pattern that

> Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.

All the available patterns are:

> $$    Inserts a "$".
>
> $&: Inserts the matched substring.
>
> $`: Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.
>
> $': Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
>
> $n or $nn: Where n or nn are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: If the replacement is a variable, I don't know if it exist any $ character. Should I replace all $ by $$ for every the replacement?

Comment: If you want  `$` character instead of using it as the special patten, you need to use `$$`

Comment: @vietean Not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but whenever you want to replace something _by_ a dollar sign, you use `$$` every time as the second argument of the `replace` function. Only a `$$` safely creates a single `$` this way.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
"(?)".replace("?", "$$'")
```

$' is a special replacement pattern (nserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.) and needs to be escaped using $.

---

**How to Do This Without an Escape Sequence**

If you don't want to replace all your $ in your replacement string, you could also do something like

```
"(?)".replace("?", function() { return "$'" })
```

i.e. using a function (that returns the replacement string - no escaping needed) as the 2nd parameter.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

> The function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string. **(Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not
>   apply in this case.)**

Comment: `.replace('precedes','follows')`.

Comment: If the replacement is a variable, I don't know if it exist any $ character. Should I replace all $ by $$ for every the replacement?

Comment: Yes you should what exactly are you trying. There could be something easier.

Comment: @vietean - see the 2nd section.